# Trying to integrate openId in spring but gives BeanDefinitionParsingException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I m new to spring and i m trying to integrate openId in my application

I keep getting this exception and hence 404 error.

Console log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: spring-security-web classes are not available. You need these to use <filter-chain-map>
```

My web.xml:-

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping> 

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>
```

part if my dispatcher-servlet.xml:-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kratin" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <!-- Default converters -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

index.jsp:-

```
<a href="j_spring_openid_security_check?openid_identifier=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id">Login via Google</a><br></br>
```

Login via any Open ID Provider

applicationContext-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <openid-login>
        <attribute-exchange>
              <openid-attribute name="email" type="http://axschema.org/contact/email" required="true" />
              <openid-attribute name="fullname" type="http://axschema.org/namePerson" />
              <openid-attribute name="first" type="http://axschema.org/namePerson/first" />
              <openid-attribute name="last" type="http://axschema.org/namePerson/last" />
        </attribute-exchange>
    </openid-login>
    <logout />
</http>

</beans:beans>
```

Can anyone please guide me if i have made any mistake or help me with some solution! 
Are there any other requirements for openId in spring

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you have spring-security-web and the servlet apis on your classpath. For example, if you are using Maven you would ensure the following was in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'parent'; org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' is defined: Did you forget to add an <authentication-manager> element to your configuration (with child <authentication-provider> elements)?

Comment: spring-security-web jar was missing. i added it, but now i m getting the above exception. I just need to implement openId in spring that would allow the user to login using thr google account and extract thr email_id and name and save in database.

Comment: If I answered your question correctly, you should mark it as accepted and create a new question. Otherwise it will become difficult for others to find answers on here.